# What is the reason for some flashlights emitting light in a square shape?

Tags: led, design, light

Here's an image of a flashlight that produces light in a "square" shape:

[image]

What is the purpose of this square light pattern, and why was it designed as a square as opposed to the traditional circular light beam typically emitted by flashlights? You'd normally expect a flashlight to emit light in a circle shape, not a square one as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: A square LED is going to make a square beam when focussed by the lens.

Comment: If LEDs are made on a wafer, they are singulated by sawing them into dice, so the square shape is a natural consequence of that.  Sawing them into rounds could maybe be done with a laser saw but it would be expensive and wasteful.

Comment: This is an optics question, not an electricity question

Comment: No special purpose, just an optical effect. At some lens position, then the LED at lens focus, you get image of LED

Comment: The traditional circular light beam was from filament bulbs but not from a LED.

Comment: The picture you project with that beam is actually an image of the square LED.  Those lines you see are the metal layers and bond wires that power the diode!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The light source in this flashlight (an LED) is square, so the lens projects a square beam. Depending on the lens's focus and quality, a more-or-less sharp image of the LED chip is projected.

This is not "by design" in the sense that somebody thought it would be a great idea to have a square light beam; it is because making round LED chips is much more expensive (not impossible, though). Compensating for the square light source would also add extra costs.

Comment: One could also make an adapted lens, but that is expensive as well. Basically this is just a cheap flashlight with low-end functional design.

Comment: yes, this is definitely a cheap flashlight, I bought it for $2 just wondered how would it emit light, lol

Comment: This effect is much less pronounced (and sometimes unnoticeable) in flashlights that use multiple smaller LEDs.  The individual squares overlap, blur together, and approximate the round pattern we expect.

Answer (score 2):

I have a LED flash light which can change the focus of the lens so it can light a small spot or a wide area.

When changing to the smaller spot the lighted area gets more and more square. I can't change it to a sharp edged spot, but I suspect your flashlight has the LED in the focus of the lens and so emits a clear image of the LED area. Normally an unwanted effect.